# Loading page instantly using Bootstrap, Lazyload and Masonry

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, lazy-loading, jquery-masonry

Currently, I'm using Bootstrap, lazyload and masonry to implement a grid view.

I'm facing a couple of issues:

1. Using lazyload causes the grid elements to overlap.
2. The page doesn't load with proper masonry layout. There is a 3-second delay when I can see the entire masonry grid shift from left(undesired) to center(desired).

The 2nd issue was resolved when I loaded all my js libraries (jQuery, Bootstrap, Masonry and Lazyload) in the `<head>` tag. However, this is slowing down my website a lot and I wanted to put in the end just before closing the `<body>` tag.

```js
  // Takes the gutter width from the bottom margin of .post

  var gutter = parseInt(jQuery('.post').css('marginBottom'));
  var container = jQuery('#posts');



  // Creates an instance of Masonry on #posts

  container.masonry({
    gutter: gutter,
    itemSelector: '.post',
    columnWidth: '.post'
  });



  // This code fires every time a user resizes the screen and only affects .post elements
  // whose parent class isn't .container. Triggers resize first so nothing looks weird.

  jQuery(window).bind('resize', function() {
    if (!jQuery('#posts').parent().hasClass('container')) {



      // Resets all widths to 'auto' to sterilize calculations

      post_width = jQuery('.post').width() + gutter;
      jQuery('#posts, body > #grid').css('width', 'auto');



      // Calculates how many .post elements will actually fit per row. Could this code be cleaner?

      posts_per_row = jQuery('#posts').innerWidth() / post_width;
      floor_posts_width = (Math.floor(posts_per_row) * post_width) - gutter;
      ceil_posts_width = (Math.ceil(posts_per_row) * post_width) - gutter;
      posts_width = (ceil_posts_width > jQuery('#posts').innerWidth()) ? floor_posts_width : ceil_posts_width;
      if (posts_width == jQuery('.post').width()) {
        posts_width = '100%';
      }



      // Ensures that all top-level elements have equal width and stay centered

      jQuery('#posts, #grid').css('width', posts_width);
      jQuery('#grid').css({
        'margin': '0 auto'
      });



    }
  }).trigger('resize');


  $("img.lazy").lazyload();
```

```html
<header id="header" class="container">
  <h1>Bootstrap 3 + Masonry 3</h1>
  <p class="lead">
    This is deployed with the <code>#grid</code> div fluid (that is, it has no Bootstrap <code>.container</code> class). To make it fixed simply add the <code>.container</code> class to it. Use the media queries in <strong>style.css</strong> to change
    the grid's post widths and margins.
  </p>
  <hr>
</header>



<!-- Posts -->

<!-- <div id="grid" class="container"> -->
<div id="grid">
  <div id="posts">
    <div class="post">
      <img class="lazy" data-original="http://placehold.it/200x200" width="200" height="200">
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <img class="lazy" data-original="http://placehold.it/400x500" width="400" height="500">
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <img class="lazy" data-original="http://placehold.it/600x200" width="600" height="200">
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <img class="lazy" data-original="http://placehold.it/700x300" width="700" height="300">
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <img class="lazy" data-original="http://placehold.it/700x400" width="700" height="400">
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <img class="lazy" data-original="http://placehold.it/400x300" width="400" height="300">
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <img class="lazy" data-original="http://placehold.it/200x500" width="200" height="500">
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <img class="lazy" data-original="http://placehold.it/500x500" width="500" height="500">
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <img class="lazy" data-original="http://placehold.it/200x500" width="200" height="500">
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <img class="lazy" data-original="http://placehold.it/600x200" width="600" height="200">
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <img class="lazy" data-original="http://placehold.it/500x400" width="500" height="400">
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <img class="lazy" data-original="http://placehold.it/200x200" width="200" height="200">
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <img class="lazy" data-original="http://placehold.it/500x200" width="500" height="200">
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <img class="lazy" data-original="http://placehold.it/300x300" width="300" height="300">
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <img class="lazy" data-original="http://placehold.it/500x500" width="500" height="500">
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <img class="lazy" data-original="http://placehold.it/700x500" width="700" height="500">
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <img class="lazy" data-original="http://placehold.it/600x300" width="600" height="300">
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <img class="lazy" data-original="http://placehold.it/400x400" width="400" height="400">
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <img class="lazy" data-original="http://placehold.it/400x300" width="400" height="300">
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <img class="lazy" data-original="http://placehold.it/700x400" width="700" height="400">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<!-- Footer -->

<footer id="footer" class="container">
  <hr>
  <p>Thanks for watching!</p>
</footer>
/* Default tags and Bootstrap classes */

body {
  font-family: 'PT Sans Caption', sans-serif;
  color: #000099;
  padding: 40px 0;
}

.lead {
  padding: 40px 0;
}


/* Grid */

#posts {
  margin: 30px auto 0;
}

.post {
  margin: 0 0 50px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.post img {
  padding: 0 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

#grid.container .post img {
  padding: 0;
}


/* Medium devices */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #grid > #posts .post {
    width: 335px;
  }
  #grid > #posts .post.cs2 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .post img {
    padding: 0;
  }
}


/* Medium devices */

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #grid > #posts .post {
    width: 445px;
  }
  #grid > #posts .post.cs2 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}


/* Large devices */

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  #grid > #posts .post {
    width: 346px;
  }
  #grid > #posts .post.cs2 {
    width: 742px;
  }
}


/* Large devices min-width (1200px) + a .post margin (50px) * 2 (100px) = 1300px */


/* 1300px gives me the clearance I need to keep the margins of the entire #grid (the
bleed if you will) the same width as the .post margins posts (50px). Basically I'm
being really picky about whitespace. If you don't care, no problem, just delete this.
Can this be done with Masonry options? */

@media (min-width: 1300px) {
  #grid {
    left: -50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    position: relative;
  }
  #grid.container {
    left: auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
  }
}
```

Here is the fiddle with relevant code: https://jsfiddle.net/rp0hm3h6/4/

Answer (score 0):

It's known issue of image lazy loading, and the solution is to set correct width and height attributes for each image, so that browser will know their size without loading actual image files.

Comment: Look at https://jsfiddle.net/rp0hm3h6/6/ I've added `height: auto;` for `.post img` selector and small javascript at the beginning for padding-bottom trick (each image is wrapped into a div with zero height and padding-bottom set to image_height/image_width*100%).

Answer (score 0):

One option is to try adding a style attribute to each img along with the actual img width and height, so lazy load will have the width's and heights needed for masonry to layout the grid.

```
<img class="lazy" data-original="http://placehold.it/200x200" width="200" height="200"  
style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
```